# Can't change default action in RouteConfig MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a strange behavior of configured route in Route Config in MVC5 app.
So, actually I try to do pretty much easy thing - change default action of a route.
To do that I've changed the defaults of a route, instead of having *action = "Index"*, I've changed it to my required action *AddUser* (Look at the code below).

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "ManageUser",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "ManageUser", action = "AddUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ); 
         }
       }
```

And I've next controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
public class ManageUserController : Controller
{
// GET: ManageUser/AddUser
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddUser()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

So, now I expect that whenever user goes by ***URL: ManageUser/*** he'll be redirected to defined default action but it doesn't happen, I just have 404 error. I can fix it simply by adding Index action and then redirect to AddUser, but it doesn't seem right to me. Could somebody help me understand what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your config should look like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
         "ManageUser",
         "ManageUser/{action}/{id}",
         new { controller = "ManageUser", action = "AddUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
         "Default",
         "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ); 
     }
   }
```

The first parameter is the name of the route. Second is the URL, which match URLs that start with `ManageUser`, and allows for other actions in your `ManageUser` controller. As you can see, it will default to the `AddUser` action.

And if you want to call AddUser with paramater, you must call it by full url `ManageUser/AddUser/1`

Comment: I've already tried it and unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: You could try to change /{action}/{id} to /{*path}, but I don't think i will help much - just a dumb guess.

Try to go deeper and look how your routes mapping works.